# dojo require and scope

Tags: javascript, dojo

Can anyone explain to me why when `drawSection` is called 'this' value becomes the global scope ?.

Is there anyway to use require here without having to save the widget in another variable before i lose it ?

```
define("my/TextBox", [
  "dojo/_base/declare",
  "dijit/form/ValidationTextBox"
], function(
declare, ValidationTextBox
) {

   function drawSection() {
      alert(this);
      require(["dojo/dom-construct"], function(domConstruct) {
         alert(this); // this = window
      });   
   };    

   return declare([ValidationTextBox], {
       postCreate: function() {
           this.inherited(arguments);            
           drawSection.call(this)
       }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quit simple use `dojo/_base/lang`  `hitch()` function to solve the issue .

because the function inside the  `require(["dojo/dom-construct"], function(domConstruct) {....})` is refering to global context ,

so use `lang.hitch` function in the current context (by using `this`) and probleme is solved

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bRIMOs/4619pm30/1/)

and above working snippet :

```js
define("my/TextBox", [
 "dojo/_base/lang",
  "dojo/_base/declare",
  "dijit/form/ValidationTextBox"
], function(lang,
  declare, ValidationTextBox
) {

  function drawSection() {

    alert(this);

    require(["dojo/dom-construct"], lang.hitch(this,function(domConstruct) {

      alert(this); // this = window

    }));

  };
  return declare([ValidationTextBox], {
    postCreate: function() {
      this.inherited(arguments);
      drawSection.call(this)
    }
  });
  
});


require([
    "dojo/parser",
    "my/TextBox",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function(
    parser,
    TextBox
) {
    
    // important: parse document after the ValidationTextBox was extended
    parser.parse(); 
    
});
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

<body class="claro">
<input type="text" data-dojo-type="my/TextBox" />,
</body>
```

Comment: it takes the scope defined by the caller (`require`), which is `window`

Comment: Exacltly as  ben said , then `lang.hitch(this,function(){})` means execute the function in `this` which refer to the current class , in other term if we declare `lang.hitch(window,function(){})` it'll execute in the scope of `window` not the class.

Comment: hey @blu10 if the solution work , please mark the answer  as resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `dojo/_base/lang` `lang.hitch` like this:

```
  require(["dojo/dom-construct"], lang.hitch(this, function(domConstruct) {

        alert(this); // this = window

  }));
```

That's a common closure problem.
See https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/lang.html#hitch

As a good practice, I would recommend having the `drawSection` method inside the widget and the `dom-construct` required on top (you will always need it as you call it from `postCreate` so a "on-demand" require is overkill)

```
  define("my/TextBox", [
        "dojo/_base/declare",
        "dijit/form/ValidationTextBox",
        "dojo/dom-construct"
  ], function(declare, ValidationTextBox, domConstruct) {

  return declare([ValidationTextBox], {
        postCreate: function() {
              this.inherited(arguments);            
              this.drawSection()
        },
        drawSection: function() {
              alert(this);
              //domConstruct.whaever you want
        }; 
  });
  });
```